# Testing springboot applications using Junits (Test methods for classes which require constructors that were autowired)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have the following class which I need to test using Junits

```
@Service
public class MyStorageService {
    private final Path fileStorageLocation;

    @Autowired
    public MyStorageService(FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties) {
        fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir()).toAbsolutePath().normalize();

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("An Internal error occurred when creating directories: {}", ex);
            throw new FileStorageException("An Internal error occurred when creating directories", ex);
        }
    }
    public String storeFile(String destination, MultipartFile file) {
    //Does some copy and storage operations on file system//
    }
}
```

I have the dependent bean FileStorageProperties as given below which reads application.properties from resources folder to get root directory path:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file")
public class FileStorageProperties {
    private String uploadDir;

    public String getUploadDir() {
        return uploadDir;
    }

    public void setUploadDir(String uploadDir) {
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;

    }
}
```

I have sample Junit which I am struggling to complete

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyStorageServiceTests.TestConfiguration.class})
public class MyStorageServiceTests {
    @MockBean
    private FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyStorageService fileStorageService = new MyStorageService(fileStorageProperties);


    @Test
    public void testFileLocationCreation() {
    //assert file created logic and storeFile method logic//
    }

    @EnableConfigurationProperties(FileStorageProperties.class)
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

I need to come up with the correct way to setup my testClass, don't want the logic for the unit test case.
When I try to inject fileStorageProperties into MyStorageService constructor it comes as null.
Which will cause java.lang.NullPointerException wherever fileStorageProperties is used.
I am new to java (barely 1 month exp)
Any insight would be helpful.
USing java 1.8 and SpringJUnit4

Answer (score 1):

I was able to proceed by setting the fields in my class which were expected in my constructer:

```
    @Autowired
    private FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties;
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(fileStorageProperties, "uploadDir",    source.getAbsolutePath());
    MyStorageService myStorageService = new myStorageService(fileStorageProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Mockito @InjectMocks***

Mockito tries to inject mocked dependencies using one of the three approaches, in the specified order.

> 1. Constructor Based Injection – when there is a constructor defined for the class, Mockito tries to inject dependencies using the biggest
>      constructor.
> 2. Setter Methods Based – when there are no constructors defined, Mockito tries to inject dependencies using setter methods.
> 3. Field Based – if there are no constructors or field-based injection possible, then mockito tries to inject dependencies into the field
>      itself.

```
@InjectMocks
private MyStorageService fileStorageService = new MyStorageService(fileStorageProperties);
```

Replace With

```
@InjectMocks
private MyStorageService fileStorageService;
```

Comment: I get the following error:
`org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'fileStorageService' of type 'class com.nokia.fileuploadservice.service.FileStorageService'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null`
This is because of my constructor"`
fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir()).toAbsolutePath().normalize();`
where fileStorageProperties is still null